# Can you explain the reason for using inverse="true" in NHibeernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can you explain the reason for using inverse="true" attribute in relationship mapping in NHibeernate with an example that requires the need of this attribute to be 'true' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a bidirectional association, then from .net side, you must code both sides. Like

```
parent.Children.Add(child);
child.Parent = parent;
```

however from nhibernate perspective this will send 2 update statements by default for each of the lines. What you want is only to update ParentId column of the Child table. Inverse = true makes sure that changes made to that part doesn't cause any changes in DB. So if you use Inverse = true and just write the below

```
parent.Children.Add(child);
```

nothing will happen in the db since that is the inverse side.

Comment: Then which side is the reason of an UPDATE call to Db from the NH point of view?

Comment: Always non-inverse side causes the update. Inverse side is ignored